# "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" When trying to connect to MySQL Server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**GOAL**

I am trying to create a web app that will access to my database, and be able to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE records.

---

**PROBLEM**

I cannot connect to the database server

---

**ERROR**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
C:\Users\********\Desktop\CS\GitHub\scheduler-v2\scheduler-v2-
master\test.php:15
```

---

**CODE**

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "*******";
$myDB = "scheduler";

$conn = mysql_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
?>
```

---

**What I've Tried**

-I added the php_sqlsrv_56.ts.dll file to the extensions folder of PHP.

-I also added the extension=php_sqlsrv_56.ts.dll line to the php.ini file.

-I uncommented extension=php_mysqli.dll and extension=php_mysql.dll from the php.ini file.

I have looked at many posts and they have not helped. I am running Windows 10 x86 and PHP 7. Any ideas where I am going wrong/what I am missing to connect to the database?

EDIT: The error was that I was trying to use a deprecated method, mysql_connect, instead of the new mysqli_connect that it has been replaced with

Comment: mssql_connect ????  Try with mysql_connect

Comment: Use `mysql_connect` not `mssql_connect` if you want to use `mysql`

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. The error still occurs with mysql_connect

Comment: PHP 7?Or what version?

Comment: mysql_connect does not exist in PHP 7 = http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. Try `mysqli_connect` = http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Please USE `mysqli`  NOT `mysql` or `PDO` !!! http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, you are correct about mysqli_connect

Answer (score 2):

The error was that I was trying to use a deprecated method, mysql_connect, instead of the new mysqli_connect that it has been replaced with. For PHP versions 7 and onward, use MySQLi_connect().